# Launch a command when connected to a host

Tags: ssh, networking, scripting, access-point

In a dormitory I live in the access to Internet is somehow clumsy. The procedure follows

1. Connect to the network (via WiFi/Ethernet)
2. Login by `ssh`

   ```
   sshpass -p password ssh login@domain.edu.pl
   ```

Moreover, if I suspend my computer for a longer time, the connection breaks (using the up key gives a broken pipe), so I have to use the `ssh` command once again.

Is there any way to automate it? My idea (pseudocode)

```
onConnected: if ( ap-mac == aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff ) executeSshCommand()
onDisconnected: { closeSsh(); executeSshCommand() }
```

connected and disconnected events are respective to the kernel

```
[  457.036252] wlan0: associate with 00:22:6b:73:c5:05 (try 1/3)
```

Comment: what OS and version, what networking system (upstart, systemd, ...)?

Comment: Linux Mint 17.2, upstart, but I can migrate to systemd, since the migration will happen anyway, and an upstart solution will probably soon become obsolete

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Linux Mint, but if you have a directory `/etc/network/if-up.d/` then scripts in there are automatically run when a network interface comes up.  The env var `$IFACE` will be set to the interface when the script is run. You should be able to add another script there with your commands.